# Aurelia using Auth0Lock - Error: Route not found: /access_token

Tags: aurelia, auth0

Trying to use Auth0Lock with my aurelia app. When I in app.ts call

```
lock = new Auth0Lock('3.........', '.........auth0.com');
login() {
   this.lock.show();
}
```

The lock dialog opens, and after login it redirect to /access_token=....

I assume that the Auth0 script somehow should detect this, store the token and do another redirect, but before the aut0 runs a router error appears saying the rout is unknown.

I've tried with

```
config.mapUnknownRoutes({ route:'unknown', redirect: '#/' });
```

But that seems to prevent the auth0 to do its stuff. Any ideas what I'm missing?

I'm aware of the aurelia-authenticate plugin, but I see no need for it in this simple app.

Regards

Larsi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to specify a callback route when initializing the Auth0Lock

```
  lock = new Auth0Lock('3.....', '.....auth0.com', {
     auth: {
          redirectUrl: 'http://localhost:8080/callback',
          responseType: 'token',
          params: {
             scope: 'openid email picture'
          }
     }
  });
```

Without specifing a redirect url the `?` was missing, and a aurelia-route-not-found-error was thrown.